# gather 3 different detections of three different variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe of 96074 obs. of 31 variables.
the first two variables are id and the date, then I have 9 columns with measurement (three different KPIs with three different time properties), then various technical and geographical variables.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, 3),
  time = rep(as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:2, each = 3),
  sum_d_1day_old = rnorm(9, 2, 1),
  sum_i_1day_old = rnorm(9, 2, 1),
  per_i_d_1day_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1),
  sum_d_5days_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1),
  sum_i_5days_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1),
  per_i_d_5days_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1),
  sum_d_15days_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1),
  sum_i_15days_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1),
  per_i_d_15days_old = rnorm(9, 0, 1)
)
```

I want to transform from wide to long, in order to do graphs with ggplot using facets for example.
If I had a df with just one variable with its three-time scans I would have no problem in using gather:

```
plotdf <- df %>% 
          gather(sum_d, value, 
                 c(sum_d_1day_old, sum_d_5days_old, sum_d_15days_old), 
                   factor_key = TRUE)
```

But having three different variables trips me up.
I would like to have this output:

```
plotdf <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, 3),
  time = rep(as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:2, each = 3),
  sum_d = rep(c("sum_d_1day_old", "sum_d_5days_old", "sum_d_15days_old"), 3),
  values_sum_d = rnorm(9, 2, 1),
  sum_i = rep(c("sum_i_1day_old", "sum_i_5days_old", "sum_i_15days_old"), 3),
  values_sum_i = rnorm(9, 2, 1),
  per_i_d = rep(c("per_i_d_1day_old", "per_i_d_5days_old", "per_i_d_15days_old"), 3),
  values_per_i_d = rnorm(9, 2, 1)
)
```

with `id`, `sum_d`, `sum_i` and `per_i_d` of class factor time of class Date and the values of class numeric (I have to add that I don't have negative measures in these variables).

what I've tried to do:

```
plotdf <- gather(df, key, value, sum_d_1day_old:per_i_d_15days_old, factor_key = TRUE)
```

gathering all of the variables in a single column

```
plotdf$KPI <- paste(sapply(strsplit(as.character(plotdf$key), "_"), "[[", 1),
      sapply(strsplit(as.character(plotdf$key), "_"), "[[", 2), sep = "_")
```

creating a new column with the name of the KPI, without the time specification

```
plotdf %>% unite(value2, key, value) %>%
#creating a new variable with the full name of the KPI attaching the value at the end
mutate(i = row_number()) %>% spread(KPI, value2) %>% select(-i)
#spreading
```

But spread creates rows with NAs.
To replace then at first I used

```
group_by(id, date) %>% 
  fill(c(sum_d, sum_i, per_i_d), .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(c(sum_d, sum_i, per_i_d), .direction = "up") %>%
```

But the problem is that there are already some measurements with NAs in the original df in the variable per_i_d (44 in total), so I lose that information.

I thought that I could replace the NAs in the original df with a dummy value and then replace the NAs back, but then I thought that there could be a more efficient solution for all of my problem.

After I replaced the NAs, my idea was to use slice(1) to select only the first row of each couple id/date, then do some manipulation with separate/unite to have the output I desired.
I actually did that, but then I remembered I had those aforementioned NAs in the original df.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  gather(key,value,-id,-time) %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(key,'[a-z]+_[a-z]'),
         age = str_extract(key, '[0-9]+[a-z]+_[a-z]+')) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  spread(type,value)
```

gives

```
   id       time        age      per_i      sum_d        sum_i
1   1 2009-01-01 15days_old  0.8132301  0.8888928  0.077532040
2   1 2009-01-01   1day_old -2.0993199  2.8817133  3.047894196
3   1 2009-01-01  5days_old -0.4626151 -1.0002926  0.327102000
4   1 2009-01-02 15days_old  0.4089618 -1.6868523  0.866412133
5   1 2009-01-02   1day_old  0.8181313  3.7118065  3.701018419
...
```

EDIT:

adding non-value columns to the dataframe:

```
df %>%
  gather(key,value,-id,-time) %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(key,'[a-z]+_[a-z]'),
         age = str_extract(key, '[0-9]+[a-z]+_[a-z]+'),
         info = paste(age,type,sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  gather(key,value,-id,-time,-age,-type) %>%
  unite(dummy,type,key) %>%
  spread(dummy,value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Wietze314, but your final output is not my desired one. Please tell me if I hasn't been completely clear about it.

Comment: The only thing missing is the descriptive columns (`sum_d`,`sum_i`,`per_i_d` in your example output). I assumed you did not need those, or could make them yourself, based on my `age` column.

Comment: I am afraid I am not sure how to do that starting from your output.

Comment: I added a solution to my answer. I don't fully understand why you need these redundant data in the data.frame. Maybe it is needed for the plot you eventually want to make.